# Setup NameServer in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, nameserver

When I bought a domain from godaddy, at godaddy I administered the name server of the domain to nameserver given by the hosting company.

As I want to switch to EC2 instance, does it mean I need to set the name server of the domain to my EC2 instance? what do i need to configure in my EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't run DNS out of the EC2 cloud; DNS needs to be stable and EC2 is not.

The recommended thing to do is to use [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/). This is flexible, cheap, high-availability DNS. If you'd rather host your own DNS you're perfectly capable of doing so, but this should be done on a VPS or other server.

Things to keep in mind include that if you want reverse-IP mappings, you'll have to [ask Amazon](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) to provide them (these are rather important when sending mail, and not so important otherwise). Often it's simply easier to use the DNS records you get.

And lastly, any DNS entries will have to be associated with an Elastic IP rather than the local IP on the instance. You should look up the difference between Elastic IPs and instance IPs; the short version is that Elastic IPs can be quickly switched to new instances when instances go down.

Comment: thanks Michael Lowman , from your suggestion it seems i need to follow the step http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/GettingStartedGuide/.. would you mind to elaborate for point reverse-IP mappings and how it related to sending email.. thanks again , very much.

Comment: "DNS needs to be stable and EC2 is not." QFT

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to associate an elastic ip to your new EC2 instance in the EC2 console - then direct the A Record in the DNS to that ip - If I understand the Q. correctly!

Comment: hi williamsowen, thank you for your comments.. it does make sense.. however, i could not link up end to end into one story, if i am not wrong (adding A record in the DNS happened at my EC instance, is that correct?), if yes, how would "internet" know that www.my_own_domain.com is hosted somewhere inside my EC2 instance? sorry if it is dumb Q. Thanks